# Find $\lim\limits_{p\to+\infty}x_p.$ (a problem in mathematical analysis)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, monotone-functions

Please give me some hints not a whole solution to solve this problem.

> **Problem**
>   Let $f$ be a continuous positive strictly monotone function on the segment $[0,1].$ 
>   For all
>   $p > 0$ consider the point $x_p$ such that
>   $$[f(x_p)]^p = \int_0^1[f(x)]^p dx.$$
>   Find 
>   $\lim\limits_{p\to+\infty}x_p.$

Comment: Do we need to consider two cases? i.e., strictly increasing and strictly decreasing.

Comment: I have no idea...

Comment: Guess: For strictly increasing case, the limit is 1, For strictly decreasing case, the limit is 0. I remember that the $L^p$ norm converges to the supremum norm as $p\rightarrow\infty$. Let me prove this fact once I have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proposition:
Let $C\left([0,1]\right)$ be the vector space of all real-valued
continuous functions defined on $[0,1]$. For each $p\in[1,\infty)$,
define $||f||_{p}=\left(\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{p}\,dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$.
Define $||f||_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$. Then for
each $f\in C\left([0,1]\right)$, we have $||f||_{\infty}=\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}||f||_{p}$.

Proof: Let $f\in C\left([0,1]\right)$. If $||f||_{\infty}=0$, we
are done because $||f||_{p}=||f||_{\infty}=0$ for all $p\in[1,\infty)$.
Suppose that $||f||_{\infty}>0$. By direct verification, for each
$p\in[1,\infty)$, we have $||f||_{p}\leq||f||_{\infty}$. In particular,
$\limsup_{p\rightarrow\infty}||f||_{p}\leq||f||_{\infty}.$ On the
other hand, choose $x_{0}\in[0,1]$ such that $|f(x_{0})|=||f||_{\infty}.$
Let $0<\alpha<||f||_{\infty}$ be aribtrary. Since $|f|$ is continuous
at $x_{0}$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|>\alpha$ whenever
$x\in(x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta)$. (If $x_{0}$ is an end-point of
$[0,1]$, the interval is adjusted in an obvious way.) Now 
$$
\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{p}\,dx\geq\int_{x_{0}-\delta}^{x_{0}+\delta}|f(x)|^{p}\,dx\geq\alpha^{p}\cdot2\delta.
$$
Therefore $||f||_{p}\geq\alpha\cdot(2\delta)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$ In particular,
$\liminf_{p\rightarrow\infty}||f||_{p}\geq\liminf_{p\rightarrow\infty}\alpha\cdot(2\delta)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\alpha$.
Since $\alpha\in(0,||f||_{\infty})$ is arbitrary, we have $\liminf_{p\rightarrow\infty}||f||_{p}\geq||f||_{\infty}$.
Now, $\limsup_{p\rightarrow}||f||_{p}\leq||f||_{\infty}\leq\liminf_{p\rightarrow\infty}||f||_{p}$.
It follows that $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}||f||_{p}$ exists and equals
to $||f||_{\infty}$.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

We consider the strictly increasing case.

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ be a strictly increasing function.

Firstly, we show that for each $p\in[1,\infty)$, there exists a unique
$x_{p}\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x_{p})=||f||_{p}$. Let $p\in[1,\infty)$.
Note that 
$$
f(0)^{p}=\int_{0}^{1}f(0)^{p}\,dx\leq\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^{p}\,dx\leq\int_{0}^{1}f(1)^{p}\,dx=f(1)^{p}.
$$
Taking $p$-th root, we have 
$$
f(0)\leq||f||_{p}\leq f(1).
$$
By Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists $x_{p}\in[0,1]$ such
that $f(x_{p})=||f||_{p}$. Since $f$ is strictly increasing, $x_{p}$
is unique.

Next, it is well-known that the inverse function $f^{-1}:[f(0),f(1)]\rightarrow[0,1]$
of $f$ exists and is continuous. Therefore, 
$$
x_{p}=f^{-1}\left(f(x_{p})\right)=f^{-1}\left(||f||_{p}\right).
$$
By continuity of $f^{-1}$ and the above Proposition, we have 
$$
\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}x_{p}=f^{-1}\left(\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}||f||_{p}\right)=f^{-1}\left(||f||_{\infty}\right)=f^{-1}\left(f(1)\right)=1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. Since $f$ is a positive continuous function, it admits a maximum $M>0$.
   Moreover, $f$ is strictly monotone, so the $M$ is achieved only at $x=1$ if $f$ is increasing, or only at $x=0$ if $f$ is decreasing.
   Assume, just to fix the ideas, that $f$ is increasing.
2. [Difficult point] You can prove that
   $$
   \left(\int_0^1 [f(x)]^p\, dx\right)^{1/p} \to \max_{[0,1]} f = f(1),
   \qquad \text{as}\ p\to +\infty.
   $$
3. By the previous points it holds
   $$
   f(x_p) \to f(1)
   \quad \text{as}\ p\to +\infty.
   $$
   On the other hand, $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing...

Comment: For the 2nd step, can we say that
$\lim\limits_{p\to +\infty}\left(\int_0^1 [f(x)]^p\, dx\right)^{1/p}=\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}=\sup\limits_{x}\vert f(x)\vert=\max f(x)=f(1)$???

Comment: That's exactly the point, but you have to prove the first equality (unless you have already proved it).